# I've SSH'd into a remote Linux machine. How do I play an audio file on that machine through my Macbook speakers?

Tags: linux, ssh, audio, macbook, speakers

As the title said, I have a file on my Linux machine and I want to output the audio file through my Macbook speakers. I am playing sounds via

Comment: Play it directly as a mounted drive: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5209/how-can-i-mount-sftp-ssh-in-finder-on-os-x-snow-leopard